# The open ball $B(f,1)$ in $(C[0,1],\mathbb R), d_{\infty})$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Which of the following are compact?

- The open ball $B(f,1)$ in $(C[0,1],\mathbb R), d_\infty)$, where $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ denotes the constant function at zero and $d_\infty (f,g) = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$

My guess is that this is not compact because $(C[0,1],\mathbb R), d_\infty)$ is unbounded.

- The closed ball $D(0,1)$ in $(\mathbb Z,d)$, where $d$ denotes the 3-adic metric.

My guess is that this is not compact, because $(\mathbb Z,d)$ is not complete.

---

Are either of these correct? Could anyone provide better proofs of them?

Comment: A compact subset of a metric space is necessarily closed, so this rules out the open ball as long as you can show it is not closed (e.g., exhibit a sequence $f_n \in B(f,1)$ such that $f_n$ converges, but to a function not in $B(f,1)$).

Comment: Also, your reasons for why you think those sets are not compact are not sufficient. In the first example, you say the ambient space is unbounded. But $\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, and there are plenty of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. In the second, you say the space is not complete. $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is not complete, but this is compact.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! Would you be able to provide step-by-step proofs for me to examine? I was a bit confused with this one.

Comment: The open ball is clearly bounded since it's a ball of finite radius.

Answer (score 1):

The open ball $B(f,1)$ in $(C[0,1],\mathbb R), d_\infty)$, where $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ denotes the constant function at zero and $d_\infty (f,g) = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$ is clearly bounded, since every point in it is within distance $1$ from just one point. No two points in it are as much as, nor more than $2$ units away from each other, by the triangle inequality.

But the space is not compact, as may be seen as follows. Let $g_n$ be a continuous function that is $0$ outside the interval whose endpoints are $n\pm\frac 1 3$ has the value $1$ at $n$. That sequence has no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess is that:$\\$
if $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for every $x\Rightarrow d_\infty(f,g)>0 \Rightarrow \exists$ $B(f(x),\frac{d_\infty}{2}), B(g(x),\frac{d_\infty}{2})\\ $, where $B(f(x),\frac{d_\infty}{2}) \cap B(g(x),\frac{d_\infty}{2})=\emptyset $, so this topological space is a Hausdorff Space, and since a compact in a Hausdorff space must be closed, an open ball cannot be a compact.

Proof that a compact subspace in a Hausdorff space is closed may be found in Serge Lang's Analysis book at page 32.